# yocto bitbake a recipe - df: not found

Tags: yocto

I am writing an bb file, when bitbake it, I got:

```
./install.sh: 381: ./install.sh: df: not found
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: What happens when you run `which df` from a terminal?

Comment: /bin/df ............